# Spring cloud Stream producer batch

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I have been developing a project utilizing the 1.0.0 Release of cloud stream kinesis binder (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis). I have an inbound channel (kinesis stream 1) that is being consumed by my application. my application is essentially reading modifying and writing a new message to an outbound channel (kinesis stream 2).

I am able to read messages in batch 100,200 records at a time. But when it comes to writing to the outbound stream I don't see a way to configure the outbound channel to perform batch writing equivalent to kinesis stream API's PutRecordsRequest.

Has anyone been able to perform something like this with cloud stream output channels?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just return a `PutRecordsRequest` from your `@StreamListener` and configure the `.producer.useNativeEncoding = true` for the output binding target. This way the result of the `@StreamListener` is not going to be converted to the `byte[]` and that will become a `KinesisMessageHandler` responsibility to handle that `PutRecordsRequest` payload properly. And that is possible there now:

```
if (message.getPayload() instanceof PutRecordsRequest) {
        AsyncHandler<PutRecordsRequest, PutRecordsResult> asyncHandler =
                obtainAsyncHandler(message, (PutRecordsRequest) message.getPayload());

        return this.amazonKinesis.putRecordsAsync((PutRecordsRequest) message.getPayload(), asyncHandler);
    }
```